# A word for thing(s) which are given away by relatives of a dead person

Tags: single-word-requests

Situation: After the funeral the relatives usually give away personal things and belongings of a buried person to his/her relatives, friends, acquaintances and etc.

How would you call these thing(s)?
As far as I know, there should be a separate word for it/them.

Lots of thanks  in advance.

Comment: Of course they are part of the **estate** but more directly they're ***mementos***

Comment: Maybe "belongings of the deceased"

Comment: @JimMack thank you!! That (mementos) is exaclty what I have been looking for.

Comment: "Keepsake" is another term.  (Though of course to many people they are a "burden".)

Comment: If such things are distributed according to the deceased's Will they are called bequests when the items are identified in the Will and left to named beneficiaries under the Will. Anyone who has the power to distribute items upon a discretionary basis (not including a discretionary trust) would be handing on mementos and the like. Real property, significant chattels and monies are more formerly transferred to the beneficiaries/legatees under the Will as bequests/legacies.

Comment: I second "bequests" if the person did some planning before dying.  Otherwise you could also say "remembrances".

Answer (score 2):

**There is no specific single-word for those belongings**.  As mentioned in a comment, they are part of the [**estate**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/estate) - the things left by someone who has died.

You might say that some of the **"personal belongings of the deceased"** were given away.

Answer (score 0):

I’d like to add the term “[heirlooms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heirloom),” which comes up a bit in such situations.